# remove spaces in a array php

Tags: php, arrays

for this array,

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 'HOST:' 
  [1] => 'killbill' 
  [2] =>  
  [3] =>  
  [4] =>  
  [5] =>  
  [6] =>  
  [7] => 
  [8] => 
  [9] => 
  [10] => 
  [11] => 'Loss%' 
  [12] => 
  [13] => 
  [14] => 'Snt' 
  [15] => 
  [16] => 
  [17] => 'Last' 
  [18] => 
  [19] => 
  [20] =>'id'
)
```

it has empty values.by using this code it gives

```
foreach($array as $key => $subarray) {
    $array[$key] = preg_grep('/^$/', $subarray, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
}

array ( 
  [0] => HOST: 
  [1] => killbill 
  [11] => Loss% 
  [14] => Snt 
  [17] => Last 
  [20] =>id
)
```

that means it removes all the spaces. but it has the original key values .(compair above one and bellow one. then can get a clear idea what i'm saying).but i want to have it like this.

```
array ( 
  [0] => 'HOST:' 
  [1] => 'killbill' 
  [2] => 'Loss%'
  [3] => 'Snt' 
  [4] => 'Last' 
  [5] => 'id'
)
```

key values as 1,2,3,4.... so how could i get that.

Comment: array_filter() without a callback will remove empty elements and retain associativity; then pass that to array_values() to reset the keys from 0

Comment: `array_filter()` is a good plan, but note that you will still probably want a callback (depending on your definition of "empty") because without one it will remove any falsey value, notably it will remove `'0'` which you likely want to keep since it looks like you are working with ping results.

Comment: this is a question that i have to faced from @Felix Kling 's answer. answered Apr 21 '11 at 22:38-  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750407/php-array-removing-empty-values#comment6582284_5750521[/link]

Comment: @Thusitha Sumanadasa my answer will help you.

Comment: thanks oliver A .for editing this nicely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply use this instead of `Foreach`

```
array_values(array_filter($array));
```

that will remove the space and reorder your array.

look: http://codepad.org/howl3Opj

Comment: anytime... :D, Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

That will remove all the empty values -- ie blank, `null`, `false`, zero.

If you only want to remove values that are empty strings and keep other empty values (eg zero), you can specify the second parameter for `array_filter()`, which allows you to define a function to specify which elements should be filtered.

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($val) {return $val!=='';});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Spudley that part of code is not working $array = array_filter($array, function($val) {return $val!=='';}); , giving error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: @vikastyagi - what version of PHP are you using? This code requires PHP v5.3 or higher. The error you've given looks like you're trying to run it in PHP 5.2.

Comment: @Spudley you are right, code is working on php version 5.3 thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this function it will help you to sort out the issue

```
$arr = array_map('array_values', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function

```
<?php

   $array_space = array(0,3,4,45,12,"",54,23);

   $remove = array("");

   print_r(array_diff($array_space,$remove));

?>
```

[See Output here](http://codepad.org/f1ibRrWO)

Answer (score 0):

at start you need to take the array i gave him a name $arrWords

```
$arrWords = array_filter($arrWords, 'trim');
```

after i clean all the empty spaces i will make new array keys

```
$arrWords = array_values($arrWords);
```